# Microsoft teams won't allow me to change my info

Tags: microsoft-teams

I registered for Microsoft Teams today with my uni email. The problem is that it won't let me change any account info. The following error translates as "It wasn't possible to save changes. Try again."

[image]

Comment: Could you please add more details here? Where are you trying to change the details? And which account are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to change my name, as it is misspelled. The account name is "Jose Coelho", with a cat profile picture.

Comment: It is not possible to change the name inside Microsoft Teams. You may have to contact the Microsoft support for that.